# Как удобнее делать список контактов, в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Как удобнее делать список контактов при условии , что нажимая на "контакт Петров" будет сделано некоторое событие . Например, при нажатие на "Петрова" выйдет окно . Сделать список и в него вложить кнопки ? или есть другие способы ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать таблицу и расположить в ней контакты. Также можно определить на какую именно строку таблицы кликнули и вывести данные по ней, пример:

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
...
table.setRowFactory( tv -> {
    TableRow<Person> row = new TableRow<>();
    row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            Person rowData = row.getItem();
            System.out.println(rowData);
        }
    });
    return row ;
});
```